# After upgrading to libreoffice 5.1, certain Basic macros work strangely. Why?

Tags: libreoffice

The Basic macros which were working in previous versions are currently not working or working strangely after upgrading to 5.1. What may be the reason?

What are the changes in (basic macro coding & API) LO 5.1 with respect to the previous version?

Comment: File a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of changes is at
https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/5.1#Scripting:_Python_and_Basic, including the API changes section.

When you find lines of code that are causing the problem, ask on stackoverflow.com or [the OpenOffice forum](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/) for solutions.  If it is an important bug in the API, consider [filing a bug report](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA/BugReport).

If you are not ready to debug the macros, then the alternative is to stick with an older version for now.